# Weird attr_accessible in Sorcery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

i am using the Sorcery gem for authentication. I've actually used it an another project without any problems, but i suddenly have a weird situation. My model is the originally generated sorcery User model, without any attr_accessible.

Now, i have a seeds file like :

```
users = {

:hthought => {
  :username => 'jkjhkj',
  :email => 'hkjhk',
  :crypted_password => 'hkjhjkhk',
  :salt => 'hkjhjkhjh',
  :password => '57667'
}

}

users.each do |item, hash|  
    user = User.new(hash)
    user.save!
    hash.each do |attribute, value| 
        user.update_attribute(attribute, value)
    end
end
```

Which when i execute(with rake db:seed), i get :

```
rake aborted!
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: crypted_password, salt
```

Why is that ? I really don't understand why i get this, since there is no attr_accessible in my User model. Moreover, i use the exact same code in another project and i never got this.

Any ideas why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you see the sorcery code ( https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery/blob/master/lib/sorcery/model.rb#L82 ), you can see that :

```
attr_protected @sorcery_config.crypted_password_attribute_name, @sorcery_config.salt_attribute_name
```

So it's normal to have this protected warning.

It was adding in this commit : https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery/commit/7c2e846bf5c084bea72eb6477e72daf0177d789e one year ago.

Comment: interesting, it's very weird that i did not get that in my other project, very very weird. Thanx for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a Rails thing rather than a sorcery thing. If you're new app is using Rails 3.2.3 and your old app was below that then it could be that a security tighten-up around attr_protected whitelists is causing a different behaviour. This posting maybe help :)

[Rails error: Can't mass-assign protected attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10050797/rails-error-cant-mass-assign-protected-attributes)