# Rails error: Can't mass-assign protected attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to build an extremely simple AddressBook rails application. However, I am getting this error "Can't mass-assign protected attributes: city_id". How can I fix this? Please feel free to add any comment/suggestion to your answer regarding the rails code below. Thanks.

How I created the project (from scratch):

```
rails new demo
rails generate model City name:string
rails generate scaffold User name:string city:references
rake db:migrate
```

db/seeds.db:

```
City.create(name: "City1")
City.create(name: "City2")
City.create(name: "City3")
```

rake db:seed

changed this line `<%= f.text_field :city %>` from `app/views/users/_form.html.erb` to `<%= f.collection_select :city_id, City.all, :id, :name %>`

changed `user.rb` auto-generated line `belongs_to :city` to `has_one :city`.

added `belongs_to :city` to `city.rb`

P.S: I am using Rails 3.2.3 and Ruby 1.9.3.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

There was an important security change rails 3.2.3 that requires you to allow mass assignment explicitly by setting `config.active_record.whitelist_attributes` to `false`

https://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/3/30/ann-rails-3-2-3-has-been-released/

http://www.h-online.com/security/news/item/Rails-3-2-3-makes-mass-assignment-change-1498547.html

alternatively (and better), instead of allowing mass assignment, you just have to set the `attr_accessible` for the attributes in your model that you want to be able to change, e.g.

```
attr_accessible :city_id, :name # list all fields that you want to be accessible here
```

Please check the [rails security guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.22.5/security.html#mass-assignment) for more information about mass-assignment in rails.

Comment: Setting `whitelist_attributes` to true is the new default -- that will require you to explicitly use attr_accessible. If you want to revert to the old behavior, you should set `whitelist_attributes` to false.

Comment: how to add attr_accessible if I'm adding a model using `ActiveRecord::Schema.define` in schema.rb

Comment: Don't do this, frank blizzard. Check https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/5228 for more information.

Comment: If there's one thing I've learned about rails is that they have sensible defaults. I would make sure to research this before changing the default.

Comment: Phew thanks for the detail.  "Whitelist_attributes" has to be the all-time worst name, I was convinced setting it to true would leave everything open by default...

Answer (score 3):

or you can change

```
config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict
```

to

```
config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :logger
```

I don't know why had to changed to `:logger` but this is the solution for the error.

Comment: Clarification of confusing syntax:

This line

`config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict`

should be changed to this

`config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :logger`

Answer (score 3):

Just include the datafield in the model as:

```
attr_accessible :city_id
```