# ruby on rails3 :Error: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: name, position

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a problem with ROR:

I want to creat a Model named 'category2', I used the following command:

> rails g model category2

then, I changed the file *db/migrate/20120521113409_create_category2s.rb* to :

> class CreateCategory2s < ActiveRecord::Migration
>
> def change
>
> ```
> create_table :category2s do |t|
>
>   t.string :name
>
>   t.integer :position
>
>   t.timestamps
>
> end
> ```
>
> add_column :events, :category2_id, :integer
>     add_index :events, :category2_id
>     end
>
> end

then,

> bundle exec rake db:migrate

when I open the console and input

> b = Category2.new( :name => 'Ruby', :position => 1 )

It returns an Error:

> irb(main):009:0> b = Category2.new( :name => 'Ruby', :position => 1 )

```
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: name, position

from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.2.3/lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security/sanitizer.rb:48:in `process_removed_attributes'

from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.2.3/lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security/sanitizer.rb:20:in `debug_protected_attribute_removal'

from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.2.3/lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security/sanitizer.rb:12:in `sanitize'

from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.2.3/lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security.rb:230:in `sanitize_for_mass_assignment'

from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:75:in `assign_attributes'

from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/base.rb:498:in `initialize'

from (irb):9:in `new'

from (irb):9

from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'

from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'

from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'

from script/rails:6:in `require'

from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

What it means?

If I don't add the parameters, I just input like:

> irb(main):008:0> a = Category2.new
>
> => #< Category2 id: nil, name: nil, position: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

It looks good!

But why cannot specified the 'name' and 'position'?

Thanks!

Comment: There are many questions about this exact topic.  Please search before asking.  Here's one example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10050797/rails-error-cant-mass-assign-protected-attributes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ActiveModel in Rails protects your code from mass assignment vulnerabilities by preventing you from assigning values to attributes unless you've expressly stated that this should be possible using something like [attr_accessible](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html#method-i-attr_accessible).  [This post](http://pragtob.wordpress.com/2012/03/06/secure-your-rails-apps/) gives a good explanation of what a mass assignment vulnerability is.

In your example, you would need to add something like:

```
attr_accessible :name, :position
```

to your model in order to assign those values at the time of object creation.

Comment: Thank you!  I add 'attr_accessible :name, :position' to app/model/category2.rb, it works!

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using rails version which is less than rails 4 you have to explicitly pass the parameters which you want to access. This is for security reason. However if you use rails 4 by default rails will handle this for you. Its called strong parameters.

So you've to tell to your model that let my controller and view access this attributes  as stayfoolish said above.

```
  attr_accessible :name, :position
```

Answer (score 0):

Just include the datafield in the model as

`attr_accessible :name, :position`