# Can't mass-assign protected attributes but assign in attr_accessible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I got a weird error:

> ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error (Can't mass-assign protected attributes: :firstname, :lastname)

But in my User model:

```
attr_accessible :firstname, :lastname
```

I refer to this answer [Rails error: Can't mass-assign protected attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10050797/rails-error-cant-mass-assign-protected-attributes#22703811). The error was gone but it doesn't save the values.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What version of rails are you using?  If it's rails 4 or newer you should be using "strong parameters" and whitelisting these attributes in your controller!

Comment: I am using rails 3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true
```

To:

```
config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = false
```